# Unit testing __main__.py

Tags: python, python-unittest, runpy

I have a Python package (Python 3.6, if it makes a difference) that I've designed to run as 'python -m *package* *arguments*' and I'd like to write unit tests for the __main__.py module. I specifically want to verify that it sets the exit code correctly. Is it possible to use runpy.run_module to execute my __main__.py and test the exit code? If so, how do I retrieve the exit code?

To be more clear, my __main__.py module is very simple. It just calls a function that has been extensively unit tested. But when I originally wrote __main__.py, I forgot to pass the result of that function to exit(), so I would like unit tests where the main function is mocked to make sure the exit code is set correctly. My unit test would look something like:

```
@patch('my_module.__main__.my_main', return_value=2)
def test_rc2(self, _):
    """Test that rc 2 is the exit code."""
    sys.argv = ['arg0', 'arg1', 'arg2', …]
    runpy.run_module('my_module')
    self.assertEqual(mod_rc, 2)
```

My question is, how would I get what I’ve written here as ‘mod_rc’?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far? Add your code to your question please

Comment: Not every question on Stack Overflow has to be about specific code.  This question has enough detail to identify adequate answers, and only asks one question.  As such, I'm recommending it be reopened.

Answer (score 4):

Misko Hevery has said before (I believe it was in [Clean Code Talks: Don't Look for Things](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0) but I may be wrong) that he doesn't know how to effectively unit test main methods, so his solution is to make them so simple that you can prove logically that they work if you assume the correctness of the (unit-tested) code that they call.

For example, if you have a discrete, tested unit for parsing command line arguments; a library that does the actual work; and a discrete, tested unit for rendering the completed work into output, then a main method that calls all three of those in sequence is assuredly going to work.

With that architecture, you can basically get by with just one big system test that is expected to produce something other than the "default" output and it'll either crash (because you wired it up improperly) or work (because it's wired up properly and all of the individual parts work).

---

At this point, I'm dropping all pretense of knowing what I'm talking about. There is almost assuredly a better way to do this, but frankly you could just write a shell script:

```
python -m package args
test $? -eq [expected exit code]
```

That will exit with error `iff` your program outputs incorrectly, which TravisCI or similar will regard as build failing.

Comment: Thanks. I've clarified my question since you wrote this. I want to be able to run the code with some modules mocked, so testing from the shell doesn’t quite meet what I’m asking for.

Answer (score 3):

`__main__.py` is still subject to normal `__main__` global behavior — which is to say, you can implement your `__main__.py` like so

```py
def main():
  # Your stuff

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

and then you can test your `__main__` in whatever testing framework you like by using

```py
from your_package.__main__ import main
```

As an aside, if you are using `argparse`, you will probably want:

```py
def main(arg_strings=None):
  # …
  args = parser.parse_args(arg_strings)
  # …

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

and then you can override arg strings from a unit test simply with

```py
from your_package.__main__ import main

def test_main():
  assert main(["x", "y", "z"]) == …
```

or similar idiom in you testing framework.

Answer (score 1):

With pytest, I was able to do:

`import mypkgname.__main__ as rtmain`

where mypkgname is what you've named your app as a package/module. Then just running pytest as normal worked. I hope this helps some other poor soul.